# Neo4j+Gremlin : Trouble with T.gte and floating point node attributes

Tags: graph, neo4j, gremlin

For a type of node in my graph, attribute values for an attribute(named 'some_count') is either missing or an integer or a float. I'm trying to write gremlin to filter these nodes based on minimum value for this attribute.

I first verified that the values are indeed present by firing the following gremlin

```
g.v(XXX)._().in('category').hasNot('some_count', T.eq, null).back(1).some_count
```

Next,

I tried filtering by exact value and that works and show me the matching nodes or gives an empty array if there is no match

```
g.v(XXX)._().in('category').hasNot('some_count', T.eq, null).back(1).has('some_count', T.eq, 120000.0d)
```

But the following query that uses the 'greater than or equal to' comparator doesn't work.

`g.v(XXX)._().in('category').hasNot('some_count', T.eq, null).back(1).has('some_count', T.gte, 1.0d)` this returns nil (I'm querying via ruby/rails using [Neo4j AR Adapter](https://github.com/yournextleap/activerecord-neo4j-adapter) )

Instead of returning an empty array for no match, it returns a nil, which tells me something could be wrong with the query itself. I'm running neo4j community server 1.8.

Is there a way I can ask Neo4j to log errors/queries, to see what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Couldn't you just execute the query over the database from the Neo4j Webadmin, starting the neo4j server? https://vimeo.com/53867161 for a small tutorial on how to do it (you can adjust neo4j-server.properties also)

Answer (score 0):

Add **Tokens.** to your T.gte.

```
g.v(XXX)._().in('category').hasNot('some_count', Tokens.T.eq, null)
  .back(1).has('some_count', Tokens.T.gte, 1.0d)
```

Comment: Why does this fix it?